# Исправить код resize

Tags: php

Вот код, он работает, НО как-то он неправильно ресайзит, ресайзит по высоте скоре чем по ширине , если я гружу картинку 1000х600 то в одном случае должно бы загрузиться без изменений а вдругом случае должно быть 1000х400 но оно сделает 700х400 и тд както не правильно както в зависимости от рисунка не пому. Мог бы мне кто помочь исправить?

```
class ImageResize
    {
    private $image;
    private $width;
    private $height;
    private $type;

    function __construct( $file )
    {
    if ( ! file_exists( $file ) ) {
    exit( 'File does not exist' );
    }
    if ( ! $this->setType( $file ) ) {
    exit( 'File is not an image' );
    }
    $this->openImage( $file );
    $this->setSize( );
    }

    private function setType( $file )
    {
    $pic = @getimagesize( $file );
    switch( $pic['mime'] )
    {
    case 'image/jpeg':
    $this->type = 'jpg';
    return true;
    case 'image/png':
    $this->type = 'png';
    return true;
    case 'image/gif':
    $this->type = 'gif';
    return true;
    default:
    return false;
    }
    }

    private function openImage( $file )
    {
    switch( $this->type )
    {
    case 'jpg':
    $this->image = @imagecreatefromJpeg( $file );
    break;
    case 'png':
    $this->image = @imagecreatefromPng( $file );
    break;
    case 'gif':
    $this->image = @imagecreatefromGif( $file );
    break;
    default:
    exit( 'File is not an image' );
    }
    }

    private function setSize( )
    {
    $this->width    = imageSX( $this->image );
    $this->height   = imageSY( $this->image );
    }

    function resize( $width = false, $height = false )
    {
    if ( is_numeric( $width ) && is_numeric( $height ) && $width > 0 && $height > 0 ) {
    $newSize = $this->getSizeByFramework( $width, $height );
    }
    elseif ( is_numeric( $width ) && $width > 0 ) {
    $newSize = $this->getSizeByWidth( $width );
    }
    elseif ( is_numeric( $height ) && $height > 0 ) {
    $newSize = $this->getSizeByHeight( $height );
    }
    else {
    $newSize = array( $this->width, $this->height );
    }
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor( $newSize[0], $newSize[1] );
    imagecopyresampled( $newImage, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newSize[0], $newSize[1], $this->width, $this->height );
    $this->image = $newImage;
    $this->setSize( );
    return $this;
    }

    private function getSizeByFramework( $width, $height )
    {
    if ( $this->width <= $width && $this->height <= $height ) {
    return array( $this->width, $this->height );
    }
    if ( $this->width / $width > $this->height / $height ) {
    $newSize[0] = $width;
    $newSize[1] = round( $this->height * $width / $this->width );
    }
    else {
    $newSize[0] = round( $this->width * $height / $this->height );
    $newSize[1] = $height;
    }
    return $newSize;
    }

    private function getSizeByWidth( $width )
    {
    if( $width >= $this->width ) {
    return array( $this->width, $this->height );
    }
    $newSize[0] = $width;
    $newSize[1] = round( $this->height * $width / $this->width );
    return $newSize;
    }

    private function getSizeByHeight( $height )
    {
    if ( $height >= $this->height ) {
    return array( $this->width, $this->height );
    }
    $newSize[1] = $height;
    $newSize[0] = round( $this->width * $height / $this->height );
    return $newSize;
    }

    function save( $path = '', $fileName, $quality = 100 )
    {
    if ( trim( $fileName ) == '' || $this->image === false ) {
    return false;
    }
    if ( ! is_dir( $path ) ) {
    return false;
    }
    if ( ! is_numeric( $quality ) || $quality < 0 || $quality > 100) {
    $quality = 100;
    }
    $savePath = $path.trim( $fileName ).'.jpg';
    imagejpeg( $this->image, $savePath, $quality );
    return true;
    }

    }

    // Ширина и высота эскизов изображения:
    $webinar_width  = '1000';
    $webinar_height = '415';

    // Ширина и высота больших изображения:
    $meeting_width  = '1000';
    $meeting_height = '600';

    // Качество изображений:
    $webinar_quality    = '70';
    $meeting_quality    = '70';

    if ( ! isset( $_FILES['Filedata'] ) || ! is_uploaded_file( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'] ) || $_FILES['Filedata']['error'] != 0 ) {
    header( "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" );
    echo "ошибка загрузки";
    exit( 0 );
    }
    $file_name = basename($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
    //$file_name = strval( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'] + rand( 1111111111, 9999999999 ) );

    ob_start( );
    $img = new ImageResize( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'] );
    $img->resize( $webinar_width, $webinar_height )->save( '../webinar/', $file_name, $webinar_quality );
    $imagevariable_webinar = ob_get_contents( );
    ob_end_clean( );

    ob_start( );
    $img = new ImageResize( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'] );
    $img->resize( $meeting_width, $meeting_height )->save('../meeting/', $file_name, $meeting_quality );
    $imagevariable_meeting = ob_get_contents( );
    ob_end_clean( );
```

Comment: Как неправильно?

Comment: @Bridun, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. Что конкретно не правильно? Насколько помню в PHP GDLib имеет свой ресайзер изображений

Comment: я так понимаю, неправильно то, что картинки не сжимаются до нужного размера. Т.е. не из-за диспропорции все равно высота или ширина не такие как ожидаются?

Comment: да не так как ожидается, почему?

Comment: @Bridun Потому что изображение, которое вы загружаете, нельзя привести к заданной пропорции. Стало быть вам нужно сжимать картинку до минимального размера (высота или ширина) по максимальному размеру самой картинки, а другой считать по пропорции. К примеру, у вас плейсхолдер 200х200. Вы загружаете картинку 300х500. Пропорция 0.6. Сжимаете высоту до 200. Ширину считаете 300*0.6 = 180. Получается 180x200. Дальше располагаете ее по центру или как вам удобно. Ну и еще, при загрузке можно прикрутить валидатор, чтобы соблюдались пропорции.